# Linux expect script

Tags: expect

I've spent the better part of 8 hours trying to figure this out with google, so I hope this warrants asking here.

I need a script that will auto-enter a password when I try to connect from my lubuntu image in vmware to a physical device connected by usb.

I've tried at least 50 different scripts I've found online, but none of them worked (or even recognised spawn as a command)

This is my script:

```
#!/usr/expect

spawn CPY2T_old.sh  
expect  "root@10.9.8.2's password:"   
send "ThePassword"
expect eof
```

The contents of CPY2T_old.sh is

```
#!/bin/bash

cd hellolinux/src/Exercise$1 
scp $2 root@10.9.8.2:
```

The above bash script works fine, but I have to enter the password, which is what I'm trying to avoid in the first place. The expect script gives the following when I execute in cmd:

```
spawn: command not found
couldn't read file "root@10.9.8.2's password:": no such file or directory

The program 'send' can be found in the following packages:
 * mailutils-mh
 * nmh
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
couldn't read file "eof": no such file or directory
```

I've downloaded mailutils and nmh at least a dozen times by now as well. Elsewhere I read I need to @echo off at the top, but this command isn't recognised and gives an error.

EDIT: I can't do passwordless ssh to this device, so please don't suggest it.

Comment: @ Tachyon :  You have to pass command line arguments to the bash script. Right? Where it is passed to the script ? By the way, while using `send`, we have to add `\r` character as well which is equivalent of sending `Enter` key.

Comment: The expect script is not a bash script as far as I understand? If I combine the two scripts it's

`#!/usr/expect

sudo ifdown usb0
sudo ifup usb0
ssh root@10.9.8.2

spawn CPY2T_old.sh
expect "root@10.9.8.2's password:"
send "root\r"

expect eof`

Comment: Correct. When you have defined the `shebang` as `#!/usr/bin/expect`, it will run from  `Expect`. So, whatever the code you have mentioned  above will fail from `Expect`'s point of view. Because it will throw error as `invalid command name "sudo"`.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 errors: first

```
#!/usr/expect
```

You want

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
```

That should have caused an error: how are you launching your expect script?

Second

```
send "ThePassword"
```

You forgot to hit enter

```
send "ThePassword\r"
```

Answer (score 0):

#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 60

spawn ssh user@ip

expect "user@ip's password: "

send "Password\r"

interact

Note:Please be sure of all scripts are executable with command $ chmod +x #file_name or $ chmod 700 #file_name.

\r to execute

Github link:https://github.com/asarari207/Lunix_sh

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).